# How to trim the characters from the start of echo?

Tags: php, regex, string

I have

```
<?php echo $img_url; ?>
```

This outputs onto my page: http://www.website.com/folder/tree

How can I truncate/trimthe first 30 characters so it only outputs 'tree' and beyond that how can I output tree capitalized? As: Tree

All the guides I have found eliminate characters from the end of the output or specific characters or white spaces, I want to trim X amount of characters from the start and then capitalize what's left.

Alternatively if trimming the first X amount of characters can't be done can I trim a regular expression say if http://www.website.com/folder/ was always present, can I remove that and then capitalize?

Thanks

Comment: *Why* do you want to do this? There's probably a better solution for what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @AmalMurali There possibly are better solutions but possibly they would mean changing a lot of code in many files. if this were possible it would be a very simple addition to 1 file

Comment: Didn't know I could get down voted so much for asking a question :D if my method is not great, that's why I am asking it... for advice!

Comment: I'm guessing the downvotes are because you didn't demonstrate the attempts in the question itself. See http://www.sscce.org/

Comment: Oh I see, I didn't add my attempts into my post simply because they were just generic snippets I got from Google and possibly were not in the right direction to the result I wanted and would have been irrelevant.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Something like this perhaps?

```
$var = str_replace("http://www.website.com/folder/", "", $img_url);

$var = ucfirst($var);
```

Comment: This will replace specifics, so OP will have to create an array of websites that are planned to be used

Comment: @Daryl Gill the OP isn't very clear about that. I was assuming this was his own website. It's not the most elegant solution nevertheless, but I think downvoting isn't correct since it does answer the OP.

Comment: I actually went ahead and used this method, but thank you to both answers :) both will serve anyone with the same issue well.

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like this for first letter in cap.

```
$str = ucfirst(strtolower(substr($img_url, 30)));
```

and to capitalize whole string use the below code.

```
$str = strtoupper(substr($img_url, 30));
```

Comment: I think OP requires capitalization of tree, so strtoupper

Comment: But he gives example as Tree, so I make it like that anyway thanks, I will update my answer to have both the options for hime